# Pandas: Converting Timestamp and Milliseconds to DatetimeIndex

Tags: csv, pandas, date-parsing

With

```
df = read_csv('data\query.csv')
```

I'am getting:

```
    TIMESTAMP   MILLISECONDS    PRICE
0   15.10.2012 08:00:06     350     24.6
1   15.10.2012 08:00:06     630     24.7
2   15.10.2012 08:00:06     640     24.9
3   15.10.2012 08:00:06     650     24.5
4   15.10.2012 08:00:06     710     24.3
```

I figured out that this one

```
df = read_csv('data\query.csv', parse_dates=[[0, 1]], index_col=0)
```

is concatenating the first two columns to a string but still not recognizing the index as a DatetimeIndex

Additionally this one

```
Import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("15.10.2012 15:30:00 890", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S %f")
```

is doing the conversion job.

QUESTION: how to do the conversion and DatetimeIndex in one rush at read_csv?

Comment: CAn you show a snippet of the csv file? Maybe you need a converter.

Comment: My csv contains a header row, three columns, columns are semicolon delmited:                                    TIMESTAMP;MILLISECONDS;PRICE
                                                          15.10.2012 08:00:06;350;24.6

Answer (score 1):

```
In [188]: from dateutil import parser

In [189]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [190]: data = """\
TIMESTAMP;MILLISECONDS;PRICE
15.10.2012 08:00:06;350;24.6
"""

In [191]: def date_parser(s):
    return parser.parse(s[:-4]).replace(microsecond=int(s[-3:])*1000)
   .....:

In [192]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';', parse_dates=[[0, 1]], date_parser=date_parser)

In [193]: df
Out[193]:
       TIMESTAMP_MILLISECONDS  PRICE
0  2012-10-15 08:00:06.350000   24.6

In [194]: df.set_index('TIMESTAMP_MILLISECONDS', inplace=True)
Out[194]:
                            PRICE
TIMESTAMP_MILLISECONDS
2012-10-15 08:00:06.350000   24.6

In [195]: df.index
Out[195]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-10-15 08:00:06.350000]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 0):

please consider adding the converter to pandas code:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/converter.py

See also:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1180

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.to_timestamp()`?

```
df_trend = pd.read_csv('googletrends.csv',parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
ts_iphone = df_trend.ix['2007':'2013','iphone'].to_timestamp()
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html).